# Create Azure Resource Group using Bicep

Tags: azure, azure-resource-group, azure-bicep

I'm trying to create an Azure Resource Group using a `.bicep` file:

```
targetScope = 'subscription'

param environment string
param location string = deployment().location

resource resourceGroup 'Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups@2021-04-01' = {
  name: 'snapshot-generator-${environment}-west-eu'
  location: location
}
```

And for deploy I'm using the following command in PowerShell:

```
New-AzResourceGroupDeployment  -TemplateFile resourceGroup.bicep
```

but the ResourceGroupName is requested and I can't understand why and what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use `New-AzSubscriptionDeployment` instead of  `New-AzResourceGroupDeployment` for a subscription-level deployment. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/deploy-powershell) for more.

Comment: ResourceGroupName is a mandatory parameter which defeats the purpose of using a bicep file

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/deploy-powershell#deploy-local-bicep-file